# A song that was once meant for other singer, but later also sung by the author himself

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, idiom-requests

What do you call a song which was once written for some other artist by an author, and later sung by the author him(her)self?

we call it "cover" if the song is played by other(not original) artist, but is there a specific word if "other artist" is the author?

Comment: I feel it is highly unlikely there is word for this. A 'cover' is a rerecording of a song originally sung by another artist (whether or not they wrote the song). So logically the author could subsequently record the song originally sung by someone else and it would still be a cover.

Comment: Actually cover has no implication about rerecording.  Some cover bands never see the inside of a recording studio.  Also, some songs are bigger than any of the artists that sing them.  Thus covering is about who not what.  There is such a thing as a KISS cover band.  But no one "covers" When The Saints Go Marching In.  But I also never heard of a word for a song sung but it's author.

Comment: Related: https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/33/what-is-the-difference-between-a-cover-and-a-remake-of-a-song. "Cover" has nothing to do with original song writer, it depends on who recorded (or possibly popularized) the song first. So one can in theory cover their own song.